# Springfox Bean Validations @Size annotation does not work properly on List

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, bean-validation, springfox

I am using springfox bean validators to extract field limit information into the generated swagger json file，Here is the way I use:

```
    @ApiModelProperty("str1")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 200, message = "length 1-200")
    private String str1;

    @ApiModelProperty("list1")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100, message = "size 1-100")
    private List<String> list1;
```

In the generated json file：

```
str1:- {
  type: "string",
  description: "str1",
  allowEmptyValue: false,
  minLength: 1,
  maxLength: 200
},
list1:- {
  type: "array",
  description: "list1",
  allowEmptyValue: false,
  items:- {
    type: "string"
  }
}
```

`@Size` annotation does not work properly on `List`

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that is not yet supported by springfox. I have modified the code and the submitted code is merged. It is expected to be released in version 3.0.
[pull request link](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/pull/3259)